# What action should be taken when OP does not respond on his/her question?

Tags: feature-request

Many times there is a situation on Stack Overflow when the OP does not respond on his/her question.

They ask a question but there is something which should be clearer in the question.

Then someone asks the OP:

```
How you want it to work?
When you tried with this method, what was the issue? 
Have you tried in this way? 
What exactly you mean?
```

If the OP does not respond to this type of question, then what was the meaning of asking?

I wanted to know if there is any action to be taken on such type of questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

Has *nobody* been able to understand it?

How long have you waited for the user to respond?

Is the user a registered user?

Have they been back to the site since?

I'd say that if it's been months, they have 1 rep, never been back since, and nobody has been able to understand there question, you could vote to close (if you have sufficient rep), or possibly flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force anything from the OP except for ask questions and wait for them to be answered with patience. If they do not respond, then just hop on to next question with a smile on face and help some other OP resolve his issues.

The no reponse might also mean, that OP has already found a resolution for his problem or probably he is still immature to help the community with the solution he has found or OP might just be new registered user, trying to register on each and every site for fun.

As @Benjol has suggested, you can flag to moderator's attention if you have waited long enough for the response from OP.